# How to join points for businesses with administrative shapefile and keep both points and administrative divisions on map

Tags: arcgis-pro, intersection, spatial-join, overlay, point-in-polygon

I have an administrative shapefile of Jamaica, and I have a layer with the coordinate locations of a few hundred businesses. I have spatially joined the business layer with the shapefile layer to obtain a layer with the various administrative divisions a particular business is in(local, regional etc).

However, when I select only this layer in the project, the map only displays the positions of the businesses in the country, but not the divisions in which they are located. This is because I have to choose an output class for the join. However, I want to be able to view both the individual locations and the shapefile divisions without having to select 2 features. I am very new to ArcGIS Pro and I assumed overlay would accomplish this, but it did not work.

How can I go about achieving this?

1. What I want from One Combined Layer:

[image]

2. What I currently get from the spatially joined output:

[image]